# finding all data with change on specific attribute in sequelize express

Tags: postgresql, express, sequelize.js

I am working on sequelize to find all data with changes in attribute

```
const chats = Chat.findAll({attributes: [message: decrypt(message)]);
```

simply I wanted to return chats with the decrypted message, I didn't want to decrypt the message  after finding the chat and looping through it

Answer (score 0):

you can try implementing the setter & getter to your model inside User.init(), it will automatically decrypt the field's value after the query

```
 message: {
                type: DataTypes.STRING,
                get() {
                    return decrypt(this.getDataValue('message'));
                }, 
                set(value) {
                    this.setDataValue('message', encrypt(value));
                }
            },
```

here's the [docs](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/getters-setters-virtuals/)